# Storing Form data into file using rest?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am learning how to write REST APIs! How can I store form values into a text file, using rest calls?

index.html

```
<form action="rest/product/adddata" method="post">  
   Enter Id:<input type="text" name="id"/><br/><br/>  
   Enter Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>  
   Enter Price:<input type="text" name="price"/><br/><br/>  
   <input type="submit" value="Add Product"/>  
</form>
```

service.java

```
@Path("/product")  
public class ProductService{  
    @POST  
    @Path("/adddata")  
    public Response addUser(  
        @FormParam("id") int id,  
        @FormParam("name") String name,  
        @FormParam("price") float price) {  

        return Response.status(200)  
            .entity(" Product added successfuly!<br> Id: "+id+"<br> Name: " + name+"<br> Price: "+price)  
            .build();  
    }  
}
```

I want to add value of `id`, `name` and `price` to a file. Where do I need to write function for adding data to file?

Comment: You should write to file inside the `addUser()` method.  You could add the code directly there or you can call a helper method which does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

write code into

```
public Response addUser(  
        @FormParam("id") int id,  
        @FormParam("name") String name,  
        @FormParam("price") float price) {  
        saveFile(id,name,price);

        return Response.status(200)  
            .entity(" Product added successfuly!<br> Id: "+id+"<br> Name: " + name+"<br> Price: "+price)  
            .build();  
    }
```

write code into saveFile to save into file

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for doing this will be to create another class which can write and read from files. And inject that class in this rest endpoint.

*Because The direct code in rest endpoint class should be to handle request not to write files*

```
class FormSynchronizer {
    public static final File FORM_BASE = new File(...); // The location of directory which will contain all these files

    public void storeFile(Map map, String fileName){
        File toStoreFile = new File(FORM_BASE, fileName);
        /* Write code to store file */
    }
}
```

Inject this class in your rest endpoint class

```
public class ProductService{

    @Inject FormSynchronizer formSynchronizer;

    @POST  
    @Path("/adddata")  
    public Response addUser(  
        @FormParam("id") int id,  
        @FormParam("name") String name,  
        @FormParam("price") float price) {  

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("id", id);
        /* put all data you want to store in this map */
        formSynchronizer.storeForm(data, "FORM_" + new Date().getTime()); // I used current time prefixed with 'FORM_' string as file name

        return Response.status(200)  
            .entity(" Product added successfuly!<br> Id: "+id+"<br> Name: " + name+"<br> Price: "+price)  
            .build();  
    }  
}
```

Use jackson to Convert Map Object to JSON file and vice-versa.
[map to / from json file](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/jackson/convert-java-map-to-from-json-using-jackson-example/)

Comment: This looks great, but I already have a file on server. I just want to add data to it. And the data which I want to store isnt key value pair, just the value. like 1, somename, 123

Comment: I just shown you how you can do this. You can do whatever you want in `storeFile` method and modify it as you want. The point is you should create another class and write code their to store or append your data. Actually I should have advised you to store data in xml file. Which is most common way to store data.